# Java Exception.getMessage() returns -1

Tags: java, debugging, exception

I am trying to debug a piece of ***production*** code. I did not write it, so please do not criticize it. I know it is terrible practice for multiple reasons, and I would change it if I could, but I can't.

The code looks like:

```
try
{
    ...
    // Multiple lines of code that can throw exceptions
    ...
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

***Nowhere in those multiple lines of code is an exception thrown manually.***

Despite this, the following is the entirety of what is printed in the case I'm trying to debug:

```
Exception: -1
```

The Java documentation for Throwable.getMessage() says

```
getMessage

public String getMessage()
    Returns the detail message string of this throwable.

    Returns:
        the detail message string of this Throwable instance (which may be null).
```

All non-native library methods that can throw exceptions are correctly caught around where they are called within the larger try-catch block. So, speaking specifically in regards to Exceptions in the standard JDK, are there any possible Exceptions whose messages are simply "-1"?

Comment: It might be an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You could use `e.printStackTrace()` instead to get more information.

Comment: @bubletan That seems like a really good guess.

Comment: Dude - you absolutely need to use getStackTrace(), or reproduce the problem in a debugger and look at the Exception's stackTrace.  Until you do that, you're just "guessing".  And "guessing" is "Bad"...

Comment: @paulsm4 I said I didn't write the code. I intend to put the stack trace print out there in our next release, but that really doesn't solve the problem in the interim. I was able to locate the exception, and it was indeed an OutOfBoundsException as many people "guessed". Because of their "guess" I was able to determine what was causing the bug and am now able to replicate it consistently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception name is often a really important part of the exception. Sometimes it's the *only* thing in the exception. See javadoc of [`getMessage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage--):

> Returns the detail message string of this Throwable instance (which **may be null**).

Examples of exceptions with no message:
   [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)
   [`StackOverflowError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

So, `println(e.getMessage())` is often meaningless, because it's nothing or entirely without context.

Examples of exceptions where message is meaningless without exception name:
   `-1`            [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)
   `foo.txt`   [`FileNotFoundException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

**Always** include the exception name too, e.g. using [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#toString--):

```
System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
```

String concatenation will automatically use `toString()`, so it can also be just:

```
System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
```

Most of the time, it is better to print the stacktrace, so you can see *where* in the code the exception occurred:

```
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

you will see where the exception is thrown, and why. My guess is it's going to be an array IndexOutOfBound exception

Comment: I'm fully aware of printStackTrace(), but I'm not able to modify the code because it's in a production environment and I'm unable to figure out how to reproduce the exception in a testing environment.

Comment: I do think your guess is a good one though, and probably correct.